# expressing sum of geometric sequence in sigma notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why is $b*\frac{a^n-1}{r-1}$ equal to $b*\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i$ ?

The confusion I get here is that we are taking $n-1$ in sigma notation, but not $n$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Did you mean $a$ where you typed $r$?

Comment: it's common ratio and $r$ was a notation for it that I was taught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be simplified to:

> Prove that $$\dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i$$

Let $S=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i=1+a+a^2+\cdots a^{n-1} \\ aS=a+a^2+a^3+\cdots a^{n-1}+a^n \\ aS-S=a^n-1 \\ (a-1)S=a^n-1 \\ S=\dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}$

Comment: Appreciated! thanks

Comment: Why don't you vote up me ? @MartynasKrupskis

Comment: I did approve your question and upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

To show that
$$\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i$$
start from the summation
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i=1+a+a^2+\cdots +a^{n-1}$$
and then recognize that
$$a^n-1=(a-1)(1+a+a^2+\cdots +a^{n-1})$$
therefore
$$\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=1+a+a^2+\cdots +a^{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i$$
It is important to discern that in order for the series to converge, we require that $| a | < 1$.